# Oracle 11g connection issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I installed oracle 11g in a vm with windows xp, set SID = orcl, but when i try to connect with SQL developer to db im getting the error `ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect`

I checked on the listener, using lsnrctl services and it says that listener doesnt support any services

EDIT:
This is my tnsnames.ora file

```
>  tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: >E:\app\oracle\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
> Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
>ORCL =
>  (DESCRIPTION =
>    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = winxpora11g)(PORT = 1521))
>    (CONNECT_DATA =
>      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
>    )
>  )
```

Im kind of a newbie so any Help would be appreciated

This is my listener.ora

```
> listener.ora Network Configuration File:            >E:\app\oracle\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
> Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
> LISTENER =
>  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>    (DESCRIPTION =
>      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
>      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = winxpora11g)(PORT = 1521))
>    )
>  )
```

Comment: Your `listener.ora` is more relevant than your `tnsnames.ora`. Is the database actually up? Can you connect locally with SQL*Plus? It would normally register with the listener automatically, seems unlikely you'd have changed any init parms that would intefere with that.

Comment: No, i cant connect with SQLPlus, i get this error ORA-12560:TNS:protocol adapter error. How can i check if my database is up?

Comment: Do you have `ORACLE_SID` set in your environment? `set ORACLE_SID=orcl` for example. I'm not sure about Windows but think you need to check it has started as a service;connecting as `SYS` will also give an indication.

Comment: what's the output of lsnrctl status and lsnrctl services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old thread, but in case anyone else stumbles here. In SQL Developer, you could do

```
Connection Type:  Basic
Hostname: winxpora11g
Port: 1521
Service Name: orcl
```

This bypasses TNSNAMES.ORA and should connect you to the database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the listener appears to have been off or reset since the instance was started. The instance, by default, would be "auto-register" and would register itself with the listener upon startup. The easiest way to resolve would be to restart the OracleServiceORCL service (if it is set for "startup open" in the oracle service, which should be default -- if it isn't I can help with details on connecting and changing that via the command line).

The permanent resolution, if this is common, is to setup the service as a static entry in the listener.ora and restart the listener service.